# How can i display what number includes the three?

Tags: ruby

This code shows the 1000th number of a string that contains numbers from 1 to 999. The number currently outputted by the code is 3. How can i modify the code to put the entire number where the 3 belongs? i.e. the count of 'i'

```
i = 1
megastringa = ""
while i != 1000 do
   megastringa << i.to_s
   i = i + 1
end
puts "#{megastringa}"
puts "This is the 1000th digit: #{megastringa[999]}"
puts "The number containing the 1000th digit is #{???}" # this should return 370
```

Comment: _"put the entire number where the 3 belongs"_ - what does that mean? What's your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much easier way of doing what you're trying to achieve (without using loops)> replace your entire code with:

```
megastring = (1..999).to_a.join
puts "Entire string is #{megastring}"
puts "1000'th digit is #{megastring[999]}"
puts "first 1000 digits is: #{megastring[0..999]}"
```

However, if you're wanting the actual 3 digit answer, you do need loops and should be written as:

```
i = 1
megastringa = ""
while megastringa.length < 1000 do
   megastringa << i.to_s
   i = i + 1
end
puts "#{megastringa}"
puts "This is the 1000th digit: #{megastringa[999]}"
puts "This is the number which the 1000th digit appears #{i-1}"
```

Comment: -1 because you have i+1 inside the while. So at the time the length goes above 1000, you add another 1. You therefore have to remove this. This would work for any length so for any value 999 (as per your question) or other numbers e.g. 7, 76, 123, 2340, 8712868

Answer (score 0):

In your `megastringa`,
the first 9 digits are contributed by 9 1-digit numbers (1 ~ 9).
the next 180 digits are contributed by 90 2-digit numbers (10 ~ 99).
the next 2700 digits are contributed by 900 3-digit numbers (100 ~ 999).

So the 1000th digit belongs to the `(1000 - 180 - 9) / 3 + 1` = 271th 3-digit number, which is `(100 + 271 - 1)` = 370. So the answer is 370.

**Prove by brute force**

```
(1..999).to_a.join[999, 3]  #=> "370"
```